# MSXML Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, msxml, msxml6, msxml4

I have to deal with a legacy application that uses MSXML to write measurement data to a simple XML file. Basicly, this is what's happening:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr pXmlDocument;
HRESULT comResult = CXMLUtil::createXMLDocument(pXmlDocument);
// ... check HRESULT ...
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pXmlMainNode = pXmlDocument.GetInterfacePtr();
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pXmlSubNode = CXMLUtil::AppendNewElement(pXmlDocument, pXmlMainNode, RootTag, "");
// ... create further nodes ...
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pXmlTmpNode = CXMLUtil::AppendNewElement(
pXmlDocument,
pXmlDataSetNode,
measDataTag,
measdata,
numberOfDataItems );
// ... append further items ...
```

After each item, `pXmlTmpNode.Release()` is called. At the end, all other nodes as well as `pXmlDocument` are `Released`.

`createXMLDocument` is defined as follows:

```
HRESULT CXMLUtil::createXMLDocument(MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr &pXmlDocument) {
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2 *xmlDocument = 0;
    HRESULT comError = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument),NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&xmlDocument));
    if (comError) return comError;
    xmlDocument->put_async(VARIANT_FALSE);
    xmlDocument->put_validateOnParse(VARIANT_FALSE);
    xmlDocument->put_resolveExternals(VARIANT_FALSE);
    xmlDocument->put_preserveWhiteSpace(VARIANT_TRUE);
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr ptr(xmlDocument);
    pXmlDocument = ptr;
    return comError;
}
```

For appending new elements (i.e. `unsiged char` arrays), this function is applied:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr CXMLUtil::AppendNewElement(MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr pXMLDom, MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pParent, CComBSTR strElementName, unsigned char* pData, long nData) {
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pData1 = pXMLDom->createElement(BSTR(strElementName));
    pData1->put_dataType(CComBSTR(_T("bin.base64")));
    SAFEARRAY* psa = SafeArrayCreateVector( VT_UI1, 0L, nData);
    psa->pvData = pData;
    VARIANT var;
    VariantInit(&var);
    var.parray = psa;
    var.vt = (VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1 );
    pData1->nodeTypedValue = var;
    pParent->appendChild(pData1);
    SafeArrayDestroy(psa);
    return pData1;
}
```

Regardless of wether `#import <msxml4.dll>` or `#import <msxml6.dll>` is used, there seems to be a leak of memory. Since `measdata` etc. can be huge, that's a pretty big problem. Is there something I can do to make the code work?
Thanks, Matthew

Comment: "there seems to be a leak of memory": how did you determine that?

Comment: Calling the function several times and watching the process' memory consumption.

Comment: "process' memory consumption" and by that, what do you mean? Specifically, which counter(s). BTW, `if (comError)` should be [`if (FAILED(comError))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474(v=vs.85).aspx), in general.

Comment: use this tool if you are on solaris:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/11/finding-memory-leaks-on-solaris-is-no.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2 *xmlDocument = 0;
HRESULT comError = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument),
    NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&xmlDocument));
...
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr ptr(xmlDocument);
pXmlDocument = ptr;
```

This code leaks `xmlDocument`. `ptr(xmlDocument)` does an extra `AddRef`, but there is no `Release` for xmlDocument going out of scope. You use smart ptrs everywhere, no reason not to use one here as well, maybe something like this:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr xmlDocument;
HRESULT comError = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument),
    NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&xmlDocument));
...
pXmlDocument = xmlDocument;
```

Comment: `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr xmlDocument` can't be done; it's telling me it's an abstract class. However, adding an extra `Release` after creating the `ptr` pointer did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Use the "assign" method to avoid bumping the ref count.